# Display Modal window in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, modal-dialog, xamarin

I'm newbie in Xamarin. I'm creating a simple application with Xamarin. I have a table view in my layout. Each row of table view displays a modal window. For example the first row is used to get the full name of the user. I want to display the modal window shown (rightside) in the given figure. [image: Question]

I have created a Layout for the same as given below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="55px"
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="55px"
        android:id="@+id/txtLastName"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="55px"
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="165dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my code to display popup

```
tblrName.Click += delegate
{
    //Want to display the modal window here.
};
```

I tried to set the layout using `setContentView()` but it opens a new window while I want to display the modal window in same screen itself.

Can anybody help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`AlertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog).

In your click event, try this:

```
var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.SetView(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Modal, null));
alert.Create().Show();
```

To get values from `AlertDialog`, you could keep a reference to the `EditText` **in the dialog**. And then, in your Save button click event, simply call `EditText.Text` to get the value.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your quick response. Let me try it and I'll update you soon

Comment: One more doubt, how can I set a string as text for the EditText first name? I tried to set a value of string type as `txtFirstName.SetText(firstName)` but it is not working.

Comment: txtFirstName is an EditText inside the layout I have used in as layout inside the alert dialog.

Comment: @Anand Do you mean how to get values from the modal window?

Comment: @Anand I've updated the answer. Let me know if you have any questions.